# Enable fine grained on keycloak with docker

Tags: docker, keycloak

I have set up keycloak using docker, my problem is that I need to do some modifications on the clients that need the fine grained to be enabled. I have read the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_fine_grain_permissions) and i know I should use the parameter `-Dkeycloak.profile=preview` or `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled`. My problem is that I tried to use that on my docker execution command, but with no luck

```
docker run --rm \
  --name keycloak \
  -p 80:8080 \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=[adminPass] \
  -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true \ 
  -e DB_VENDOR=MYSQL \
  -e DB_ADDR=[SQL_Server] \
  -e DB_DATABASE=keycloak \
  -e DB_USER=[DBUSER] \
  -e DB_PASSWORD=[DB_PASS] \
  -e JDBC_PARAMS=useSSL=false \
  -e -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled \
  jboss/keycloak
```

any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is documented in the Docker image readme https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

> Additional server startup options (extension of JAVA_OPTS) can be configured using the JAVA_OPTS_APPEND environment variable.

So in your case:

```
-e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dkeycloak.profile=preview"
```

Comment: `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND` works for me. Thanks!

Note: When I use `JAVA_OPTS`, the docker container will be terminated right after startup with exit 1 error code

Answer (score 0):

Guess you might need to pass the environment variables to the JVM when starting the Wildfly containing the Keycloak WAR. There is a runner shell script that starts when launching the container. You need to add your environment variables to that call.

Comment: I am not very familiar with docker, I just followed the instructions on the docker from https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak. how do  i edit this?

Comment: Jans anwer is correct. Take the upper approach.